# Exclude cannot remove undefined on Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to remove the undefined from one object type. What I did is:

```
type T = Exclude<{
    foo: number | undefined;
    flag?: boolean | undefined;
}, undefined>
```

But the T result is still

```
type T = {
    foo: number | undefined;
    flag?: boolean | undefined;
}
```

Why the `Exclude` is not working?

Sorry, I forgot mention I still want keep the optional type. I updated the object. Suppossing we have one property is optional and another one is not. So the result I want is

```
type T = {
    foo: number;
    flag?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: From the docs, "[Exclude] constructs a type by excluding from Type **all union members** that are assignable to ExcludedUnion." (Emphasis mine.) Your type doesn't include any union members as far as I can tell, although the members do. You can Exclude on each member, or have a look at `NonNullable<>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming

```
type A = {
    foo?: number | undefined;
    flag?: boolean | undefined;
};
```

`A` can't receive `undefined`, otherwise its definition would've been

```
type UndefinableA = {
    foo?: number | undefined;
    flag?: boolean | undefined;
} | undefined;
```

Therefore, both `Exclude<A, undefined>` and `Exclude<UndefinableA, undefined>` will return `A`, since `Exclude<T, U>` does not act on properties:

> Exclude from T those types that are assignable to U

---

You can loop for all the keys and exclude `undefined` from each one:

```
type OmitUndefined<T> = {[K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined>};
```

then

```
type T = OmitUndefined<A>;
```

will be the same as

```
type T = {
    foo: number;
    flag?: boolean | undefined;
}
```

Since `flag` is optional, you can't remove `undefined` from it.

Comment: Your one remove the optional as well. I want to keep the optional.

Comment: Check if this helps solving your problem.